# Can't connect with Database with required ORACLE_SID

Tags: windows, oracle, oracle11g, environment-variables, sqlplus

I have two Oracle_SID's catdb and ORCL. Each time when connect using sqlplus I am connected to catdb. I change it as

```
Set ORACLE_SID=ORCL
```

then I can connect with ORCL but when I close cmd and try again I am connected again with catdb

I want to connect with ORCL each time I connect?
I am using 11g

Comment: Modify the environment variable at OS level. Why haven't you mentioned the OS?

Comment: os version is windows 7 ultimate

Comment: thanx Lalit !! it worked @Lalit Kumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the **environment variable** at OS level.

Changes made with **SET** will remain only for the duration of the current **CMD session**. To permanently change a variable at the command line use **SetX** or with the **GUI**

```
Control Panel -> System -> Advance system settings-> Environment Variables
```

If you have multiple instances, and want to switch to a different instance then set the respective SID in **oraenv** variable in cmd line:

```
. oraenv
```

Comment: Is there a way to quickly switch between the two database instances?

Comment: @MarkStewart Yes, use ". oraenv" to set the SID of the database you want to switch to.